# How do I make it so Python checks each possible output and if it matches it, prints it?

Tags: python

My current code is this:

```
y = int(input('Please enter a number from 1 - 100: '))

if y == 1:
    print('Y is 1.')
elif y >= 5:
    print('Y is high.')
elif y <= 5:
    print('Y is low.')
elif y != 7:
    print('Y is unlucky.')
elif y == 2 and y == 3:
    print('Y is 2 or 3.')
elif y >= 4 and y <= 7:
    print('Y is mid range.')
```

If the user inputs Y as being 6, how do I make it so that it prints all of the true statements (shown below):

Y is high

Y is unlucky

Y is mid range

Comment: Use plain `if`s instead of `elif`s?

Comment: By the way, the condition `y == 2 and y == 3` is not possible and I guess you meant to use `or`?

Comment: Another note, the condition `y >= 4 and y <= 7` can be simply written as `4 <= y <= 7`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

```py
y = int(input('Please enter a number from 1 - 100: '))

if y == 1:
    print('Y is 1.')
if y >= 5:
    print('Y is high.')
elif y <= 5:
    print('Y is low.')
if y != 7:
    print('Y is unlucky.')
if y == 2 and y == 3:
    print('Y is 2 or 3.')
if y >= 4 and y <= 7:
    print('Y is mid range.')
```

**Explained**:

if vs elif?

elif(abbreviation of term else if) condition evaluates only above if statement is not triggered. it has some distinction.

Comment: This answer could be improved by explaining *why* this solves the problem posed in the question.

Answer (score 0):

something like the code below.
The idea is to keep the functions in a list and invoke them by iterating the list

```
y = int(input('Please enter a number from 1 - 100: '))


def a(num):
    if num == 1:
        print('Y is 1.')


def b(num):
    if num >= 5:
        print('Y is high.')


functions = [a, b]  # TODO: implement more functions

for func in functions:
    func(y)
```

Answer (score -1):

YOU CAN TRY COMBINING !=7 CONDITIONS USING LOGICAL OPERATORS TO EVERY OTHER CONDITIONS.

P.S. I THINK YOUR LINE 11 LOGIC IS WRONG TOO, YOU CAN EITHER INPUT '2 OR 3' AND NOT '2 AND 3'

Comment: Don't use all-caps. It's quite intimidating. Apart, I don't see how adding `!= 7` will help...